# Running jobs on different backends at the same time

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience

```
qr = QuantumRegister(2,'qr')
cr = ClassicalRegister(2,'cr')
circ = QuantumCircuit(qr,cr)

circ.x(qr[0])
circ.measure(qr,cr)

provider = IBMQ.get_provider(group = 'open')
backends = provider.get_backend(['ibmqx2', 'ibmq_16_melbourne', 'ibmq_vigo', 'ibmq_ourense'])
job = execute(circ, backend=backends, shots=1024) 
job_monitor(job, interval = 5)

result = job.result()
counts = result.get_counts(circ)
plot_histogram(counts)
```

How do I run my quantum code on more than one backend at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to send a job to each backend you want to run on. For example, if you wanted to send to `ibmqx2` and `ibmq_ourense` you could execute code similar to this:

```
backend_1 = provider.get_backend('ibmqx2')
backend_2 = provider.get_backend('ibmq_ourense')

job_1 = execute(circuit, backend_1)  # Sends a job to run on ibmqx2
job_2 = execute(circuit, backend_2)  # Sends a job to run on ibmq_ourense
```

You can then get the results from each job normally:

```
result_1 = job_1.result().get_counts(circuit)
result_2 = job_2.result().get_counts(circuit)
```

Comment: Still the job is sent one at a time. I need a way to send all the jobs at the same time

Comment: It will send the jobs one at a time, but within the same script. They will both be put into the queue to be run on those devices. The 2nd job does not need to wait for the first job to finish before it is able to run

Comment: Is there a way to send all jobs simultaneously?

Comment: In the example I posted, it essentially sends both jobs simultaneously. There will be barely any delay between them being sent. What is the main reason you want to send jobs to multiple backends at the same time? Maybe I can explain it more related to your specific use case.

Comment: I am looking for a way to retrieve results from after the kernel has been disconnected.

Comment: You should be able to do this by either saving the job_id and using that to retrieve the job at a later time, or by going to the IBM Q Experience site and going to the results section, where you can view results from past jobs.

Comment: Thank you for your answers Matthew. I used backend.jobs() to retrieve jobs on a stated backend